# in selenium driver.close() is closing all tabs, I want to close only the current tab

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

My usecase is to close all but first tab, whenever too many tabs get opened. `switch_to` works perfectly fine, the issue is with closing. I have tried closing only one and then breaking out of loop, it still closes everything including the parent tab. My guesses are `driver.close()` might not be the right way.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROME_DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get("https://google.com")

//Do something here where multiple tabs get opened

if len(driver.window_handles) > 5:
    for handle in driver.window_handles:
        if handle is not driver.current_window_handle:   
            driver.switch_to.window(handle)
            driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.current_window_handle)
```

Comment: Your code isn't closing only the current tab... it's closing all the tabs *except* the current tab. Please clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: `driver.window_handles[0]` isn't necessarily the current window handle. Use `driver.current_window_handle` instead.

Comment: good suggestion but it doesn't solve this problem, identifying parent window for `switch_to` is working in either case but for some reason closing itn't working

Comment: That's kinda an important detail... you should add that and other relevant info to the question.

Comment: updated question as per request

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace:

```
if driver.window_handles[i] != original_window_handle:
```

with:

```
if driver.window_handles[i] is not original_window_handle:
```

Answer (score 0):

The next code only close the first tab

```
 if len(driver.window_handles) > 5:
     driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
     time.sleep(1.5)
     driver.close()
     driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1]) # This line is obligatory
```

Answer (score -1):

One of the main issues in your code is that you only check if there are >5 handles once... then you go into a loop where you close all the tabs (without checking number of handles). I've changed the logic so that it loops until handles <= 5.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(CHROME_DRIVER_PATH)
driver.get("https://google.com")

//Do something here where multiple tabs get opened

if len(driver.window_handles) > 5:
    current_window = driver.current_window_handle
    i = 0
    while len(driver.window_handles) > 1:
        if driver.window_handles[i] == current_window:
            i += 1
        else:
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[i])
            driver.close()
driver.switch_to.window(driver.current_window_handle)
```

Ideally you would take the window handle code and put it in a function so you can call it whenever you want and then just call it after you've done some actions that you know are going to spawn some new windows and have it clean them all up.

Comment: Idea is to close all but one(the root tab), not all above 5. So if 8 tabs are opened it should close 7, if 6 are open it should close 5. the number 5 is just a trigger to indicate what is the min threashold when to do this clean up ie to say it need not start closing if say only 3 tabs are opened.

Comment: And even if I assume I want to close only tabs above 5 , your code doesn't make any difference, result is the same as before.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your description of what you want.

Comment: It throws error `do: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'`

Comment: and if I split into two lines like this `driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[i])
                 driver.close()` then we get this error `Message: no such window: target window already closed`